# Android Chrome - detect if website gets fully scrolled down

Tags: android, jquery, html, dom, scroll

I have to detect if a website got fully scrolled down. On desktop browsers this works fine:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {...}
```

But on Chrome for Android, `$(window).height()`, `window.innerHeight` and `window.outerHeight` all return very strange values. The values are different to the actual pixel sizes of device's display.

How could I solve this reliably?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome for Android is clever:

1. It checks if you have defined the viewport dimension, if so it uses it
2. If not, it gives you a *standard* **non-native** resolution by setting the viewport scale
3. Either way, it then performs translations to the real size

   ```
   <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width" />
   ```

The line above will tell it to go to native resolution:

1. Set the density to the physical device density
2. Set the width to the device width

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't seem to make a difference. The values still don't match the Nexus 7 1280x800 and I still can't reliable detect if the browser is fully at the bottom.

Comment: target-densitydpi seems to be deprecated and not supported anymore.